# Update/insert table with other table in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a little trouble with SQL, I use MySQL.

I have two tables:

#Table1: Scrape

```
id        address   last_price    m2   date_last_price
======================================================
id_1234        NY       100000   100       2017-11-27
id_5678    Madrid        90000   120       2017-11-27
```

#Table2: Historic Price

```
id        price        date
===============================
id_1234  100000   2017-11-27
id_5678   90000   2017-11-27
id_1234  120000   2017-11-28
id_5678   90000   2017-11-28
id_1234  115000   2017-11-29
id_5678   95000   2017-11-29
```

I want the prices of the last date in Table2 inserted/updated in Table1.

The result must be like follow

#Result

```
id        address   last_price    m2   date_last_price
======================================================
id_1234        NY       115000   100       2017-11-29
id_5678    Madrid        95000   120       2017-11-29
```

Can you help me with this?

#Queries to create this example

```
#Table 1

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS scrape(
    id varchar(50),
    address varchar(50),
    last_price int,
    m2 int,
    date_last_price date
);

INSERT INTO scrape (id,address,last_price,m2,date_last_price)
VALUES('id_1234','NY',100000,100,'2017-11-27'),
('id_5678','Madrid',90000,120,'2017-11-27');

#Table 2

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS historic_price(
     id varchar(50),
     price int,
    `date` date
);

INSERT INTO historic_price(id,price,date)
VALUES('id_1234',100000,'2017-11-27'),
('id_5678',90000,'2017-11-27'),
('id_1234',120000,'2017-11-28'),
('id_5678',90000,'2017-11-28'),
('id_1234',115000,'2017-11-29'),
('id_5678',95000,'2017-11-29');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution using `UPDATE` with `JOIN`:

```
UPDATE scrape S
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id, `date`, price
    FROM historic_price HP
    WHERE `date` = (SELECT MAX(date) FROM historic_price WHERE id = HP.id GROUP BY id)
) A
    ON S.id = A.id
SET
    S.date_last_price = A.date
    ,S.last_price = A.price;
```

Comment: Really appreciate your help

Comment: Please, can you upvote my question? someone rate it negative... :-(

Comment: Hi @Valerica, It's me again. Sorry but I have 100k rows in the table scrapp and the query that you gave me is too slow (more than 600 sec). Do you know another way to make it faster?

I think `INNER JOIN`can be excesively slow

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You could use update with join  on the suquery for  the last price

```
update scrapp 
inner join (

    select hp.id, hp.price, hp.date 
    from historic_price hp
    inner join  (
      select id, max(date) max_date
      from historic_price
      group by historic_price.id
    ) t on t.id = hp.id and t.max_date = hp.date 
) t2  on scrapp.id = t2.id
set scrapp.last_price = t2.price,
    scrapp.date_last_price = t2.date
```

Comment: ' Error Code: 1052. Column 'id' in field list is ambiguous 0.000 sec'